# Taxonomy Terms based on already created content

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, navigation

Ok I have a client that builds homes in subdivision.  I have created a subdivision and homes content type.  What I want to be able to do is attach homes to subdivisions.

What i want to be able to do is when a subdivision is created, it will automatically be available as either a taxonomy term, or as part of a drop down available when the client is creating a new home.

Is there a way that I can achieve this using the taxonomy module?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: why you need a subdivision to be available as taxonomy term automatically when creating new node? have you tried to use node reference module [references](http://drupal.org/project/references)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using taxonomy term use the following options:

**Option 1:** [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module

> This project provides D7 versions of the **'node_reference'** and **'user_reference'** field types.

**Option 2:** [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities.